# How can I study the monotonicity of a sequence that is a difference between $2$ square roots?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I study the monotonicity of a sequence that is a difference between $2$ square roots?
$$y_{n} = \sqrt{2n + 1} - \sqrt{2n-1}$$

I have multiplied the numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt{2n+1} + \sqrt{2n-1})$, and I reached: $$y_{n} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2n+1} + \sqrt{2n-1}}$$ But I do not know what to do after this? I think this shape is more complicated than the original shape of $y_{n}$.

Also, I tried to calculate $y_{n+1} - y_{n}$ and I reached that:
$$y_{n+1} - y_{n} =(\sqrt{2n+3} - 2\sqrt{2n +1} + \sqrt{2n-1}), $$

But what shall I do next?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: $2(n+1)+1 = 2n+3$.

Comment: Can you just appeal to the fact that the continuous function $y=\sqrt{x}$ is concave down?

Comment: @amsmath  sorry I have edited it.

Comment: I want to study it without using continuity @mweiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_n = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2n+1} + \sqrt{2n-1}}> \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2n+3}+\sqrt{2n+1}} = y_{n+1}$, thus it is decreasing.

Comment: This is not $y_n$.

Comment: No it is $y_{n}$ @amsmath

Comment: You're right. I was retarded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach using elementary Calculus.  Consider the sequence $u_n = \frac{1}{2} y_n$.  Notice that $u_n = \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{2}$, which can be interpreted as the slope of the secant line joining the points on the graph of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ corresponding to $x=2n-1$ and $x=2n+1$.  Since $f(x)$ has a negative second derivative, it follows that
$$f'(2n-1) > u_n > f'(2n+1)$$

Likewise
$$f'(2n+1) > u_{n+1} > f'(2n+3)$$

Concatenating these inequalities we find that $u_n > u_{n+1}$, so $u_n$ is decreasing, and therefore $y_n$ is as well.